# Finding the value of an integral containing $(\ln x)^2$ in the denominator

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, volume

While reviewing (as an instructor/test editor) a second semester calculus exam, I came across the following problem:

> Find the volume of the solid created by revolving around the $x$-axis the area under the curve $$y = \frac{1}{x\ln x}$$ to the right of the vertical line $x=e$.

This involves calculating the integral $$\pi \int_{e}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2(\ln x)^2}dx. $$

As far as I can see, this integral is well beyond an undergraduate calculus course. The best even I can do with it is to say the integral converges (comparison test with the relevant integral of $\frac{1}{x^2}$.)

Am I missing a way to solve this integral?

Comment: this integral can not expressed in the known elementary functions

Comment: I don't see any way to avoid some exponential integral function. $\pi  \left(\text{Ei}(-1)+\frac{1}{e}\right)\approx 0.466512$

Comment: Does it come out better if you use the cylindrical shells method insted of the disks method?

Comment: Shells present the difficulty of having to express the height of each shell in terms of $y$. You have to solve $y=1/(x\ln x)$ for an expression in terms of $y$.

Comment: Are you sure it's not $\dfrac1{\sqrt x~\ln x}$ ?

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately there is no square root. The test was written by a graduate assistant for a freshman course and the department put me in charge of reviewing the test after it was submitted. But I just wanted to make sure I was not missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the integral $I$ given by

$$I=\pi\int_e^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2(\log x)^2}\,dx$$

Enforce the substitution $x\to e^x$.  Then we have

$$I=\pi\int_1^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x}}{x^2}\,dx$$

Now, integration by parts reveals

$$\begin{align}
I&=\pi\left(-\left.\frac{e^{-x}}{x}\right|_{1}^{\infty}-\int_1^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x}}{x}\,dx\right)\\\\
&=\pi\left(e^{-1}-\int_1^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{x}\,dx\right)\\\\
&=\pi/e+\pi \,\text{Ei}(-1)
\end{align}$$

where $\text{Ei}(x)$ is the [Exponential Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral)

$$\text{Ei}(x)=-\int_{-x}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}}{t}\,dt$$